# Error in define combobox

Tags: extjs

I use extjs mvc and i define combobox

```
Ext.define('Ext.view.Common.PersonageComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.ComboBox',
    alias: 'widget.PersonageComboBox',
    minChars: 0,
    store: 'PersonageStore',
    style: 'float: right;',
    valueField: 'Id',
    displayField: 'Title',
    typeAhead: true,
    hideLabel: false,
    hideTrigger: true,
    width: 300,
    queryMode: 'server',
    listConfig: {
        loadingText: 'درحال جستجو',
        getInnerTpl: function () {
            return '{Title} - {Type}<br />';
            }
        }
});
```

and in controller i defin in

```
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
requires: ['Profiler.resource.Icon', 'Profiler.resource.Size'],
stores: ['PhoneTypeStore',
    'PhoneStore',
    'EmailStore',
    'SettingStore',
    'AgentStore',
    'PersonageStore'],
models: [
    'PhoneInfo',
    'PhoneTypeInfo',
    'EmailInfo',
    'SettingInfo'],
views: [
    'Common.PersonageComboBox',
    'Personage.PhoneGrid',
    'Personage.PhoneAssignment',
    'Personage.EmailGrid',
    'Personage.Settings',
    'Personage.AgentGrid'
],
refs: [{
    ref: 'phone',
    selector: 'PhoneList'
}, {
    ref: 'PhoneAssignment',
    selector: 'PhoneAssignment'
}, {
    ref: 'EmailList',
    selector: 'EmailList'
}],
```

and this is my model

```
Ext.define('Profiler.model.PersonageInfo', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{ name: 'Id', type: 'int' },
        'Title', 'Type'],
});
```

but my page is White and dose not have error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ext.define('Ext.view.Common.PersonageComboBox', { ...

In what directory the file is PersonageComboBox.js?